# Hibernate needs to fail in order to succeed next time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, nativequery

I am writing two methods to re-initialize database in my application.
First should dynamically list all tables and then truncate them. Second one is responsible for data re-filling.

Truncate method uses native query:

```
public void truncate() throws Exception {
    List<String> names = getAllTableNames();

    names.forEach(tableName -> {
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName + " CASCADE").executeUpdate();
    });

//        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
//        entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        entityManager.flush();
}
```

Second method for data re-init just parses some documents, creates entities and saves them in bulk.

Both methods are located in service which is marked `@Transactional`.
I have two endpoints to be able to call them separately.

Now what happens is that after I truncate tables (ends without error) I call re-init and I get:

```
WARNING: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL]
```

as if the entities were still present in EM's cache.

the same happens after evicting after EM's cache (commented line).

Now two observations:

1.- the SECOND request to re-create entities is always successfull.

2.- re-create request is successful RIGHT AFTER truncate operation if I run re-create twice (first success, second fail) then truncate and then re-create. --very weired

Please guide me on what's happening and how to make this work properly.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I noticed that after calling

```
            truncateDatabaseSrv.truncate();
```

program hangs when I try to query collection:

```
        List<DocType> docTypes = docTypeDAO.getAllDocTypes();
```

so I put

```
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("COMMIT;").executeUpdate();
```

into the truncate method.

Now it won't hang and will return empty array as expected. But still when I call for the `DocType` collection re-init in the next request I get the same error as mentioned above.

Also I have noticed diry-checking is going on after truncate:

```
2:05:04,200 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:132 - Processing flush-time cascades
12:05:04,202 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:174 - Dirty checking collections
12:05:04,203 DEBUG Collections:189 - Collection found: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.fieldValidities#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL], was: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.fieldValidities#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL] (initialized)
12:05:04,203 DEBUG Collections:189 - Collection found: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.keywords#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL], was: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.keywords#ACCOUNTCONTRACTCANCEL] (initialized)
12:05:04,204 DEBUG Collections:189 - Collection found: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.fieldValidities#ACCOUNTDEBTSLIENCONTRACT], was: [com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocType.fieldValidities#ACCOUNTDEBTSLIENCONTRACT] (initialized)
```

that `(initialized)` seems suspicious to me, but that's all I have to this time...

Comment: I'm rusty with Hibernate... Did you tried something like: entityManager.getTransaction().commit() ?

Comment: it fails as soon as you try to get the transaction form em. before truncate operation. error says something like, tx is already managed.. (by @Transactional annotation I suppose)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're doing it so I'm making some assumptions here and suggesting something as how I did it.

I was using Spring/hibernate and my transactional annotations were present on both business methods on the spring bean. Something like this -

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
```

After 1st spring method is returned transaction is committed since it was container managed (not user managed which I believe is the case here). Then you go back to controller and call another method in the same Service.

If you don't want to go back to your controller then I'd suggest to have this annotation on your 2nd method and call it from 1st method (or however way you are managing your transactions) -

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = *Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW*, rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
```

I think this should work. Worth giving a try.

Comment: same thing happens. just to be clear, I'm calling truncate and re-init separately. after truncate request ends, I can see that database is cleared, so it works... it's something about entity manager that keeps him thinking that I still have tat data in place

Comment: Hmm.. if you've seen the DB is clear from your fav sql client then I would say that might be a bug in your reseed script or java code. Looks like you (or hibernate) are assigning same PK to more than one object. Just a hunch.

Comment: no reseed script Im using. that second call to the service should reseed it. and it faild for the first time. works on the second. i'm not sure whether you get me. what should I show you more?